# How to keep android emulator on top of screen

Tags: android, screen, emulation

While debugging application, emulator always get minimized while clicking on eclipse debugging environment, so its hard to see whats happen in emulator, and every time i have to maximize emulator see result of debugger, i want to know if there is any way to keep emulator on top of the screen so i can see whats going on screen while debugging the application.

Comment: just minimize eclipse window and pull it to Your size, lay it directly on the left or right side from emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three additional good ways to fix this other than the comment (which is also perfectly reasonable) above:

1. Have two monitors, eclipse running on one and the emulator on the other
2. If you only have one monitor and you're on Windows 7, then it comes with a great window stacking feature. Just press the 'window' button and the left arrow and the highlighted window will stack to the left. Press the 'window' button and the right arrow and the highlighted window will stack to the right. So you can stack eclipse on one side and emulator on the other.
3. If you only have one monitor and are on a mac, download the small and free app called cinch. Once it's installed, simply drag the eclipse window to the left and it'll stack it a-la windows 7, drag the emulator to the right, it'll stack it to the right.

Problem solved?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, iam on windows 8 and iam using the second option :).. anyway google has to include option to keep emulator on top of screen.

Comment: I have 3 monitors and still require this to stay on top. Some multitask. Others multiversumtask.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to develop on a Linux-based environment. Most Linux distributions use window managers that allow you to set any window to be always-on-top.

I also recall reading somewhere years ago that the emulator performs better on Linux environments because it's based on QEMU? Not sure how true that is / still is, though.

Comment: Yes it is actually true.